# PowerShell does not run Script from Batch File

Tags: powershell, batch, batch-file, ps1

I am working on a batch file that can run a PowerShell script when the batch file is double clicked. I am having difficulty getting the PowerShell script to do anything when activated by the batch file. The PowerShell script works perfectly when I test out the ps1 file. But once I call from it the batch file it doesn't seem to work.

Batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%FileNotifyscript.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is an escaping issue,

- cmd will interpret the inner double quotes as ending the first one
  as the single quotes have a special meaning only to PowerShell.
- use a backslash to escape one `\"` double quote

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\04\22\SU_1428283.cmd
@ECHO OFF
SET "PowerShellScriptPath=%~dp0FileNotifyscript.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ^ 
 "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"%PowerShellScriptPath%\"' -Verb RunAs}"
pause
```